# Loop in part of select statement

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to do some loop inside `select` statement?

Example: 
instead of

```
select (select count(*) from price_list where price between 0 and 1), as 1, 
(select count(*) from price_list where price between 1 and 2) as 2, 
(select count(*) from price_list where price between 2 and 3) as 3);
```

(and much more nested select statements) to do something like this

```
select @SOME_FUNCTION_WHICH_REPEAT_CODE_WITH_DISTINCT_VALUES
```

I know to do this with while loop, but I want to get results in single query...

Comment: 'Is it possible to do some loop inside select statement' - no it isn't

Comment: Why would you want to? Why not use SQL for the storage and retrieval of data, and do everything else everywhere else?

Comment: Because mysql response is much faster then code on some back-end, specially on PHP

Answer (score 0):

You would more likely use conditional aggregation something like this

```
select sum(case when price between 0 and 1 then 1 else 0) as '1',
       sum(case when price between 1.1 and 2 then 1 else 0) as '2'
etc
```

but I guess the question is how many ranges do you want and starting from what and incrementing by what. It would help if you added sample data and explained what you want rather than asking a closed question.

Comment: Data is like I wrote. need sum of every article in some price range, and that can be variable data on each request. Sometimes I need it from 20-40, sometimes from 0-60..etc

Comment: 'Sometimes I need it from 20-40, sometimes from 0-60..etc' - isn't clear enough for me are you saying you wish to limit the price range from 20-40 in steps of one and sometimes 0-60 in steps of one - in other words always in steps of one but you will provide the lower and upper bounds?

Comment: " saying you wish to limit the price range from 20-40 in steps of one and sometimes 0-60 in steps of one". Yes exactly